# How can I obfuscate my writing style when I review papers?

Tags: peer-review, writing-style, anonymity

Does anyone have any good advice for obfuscating one's writing style when reviewing papers?  I have a fear that I would inadvertently use the same turn of phrase in a referee report as in some published work, thus revealing my identity, and I'm curious if there is a good general practice to follow to mitigate this as much as possible.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you're not intending to say anything you wouldn't say to the authors in person, then you have no reason to hide your identity anyway - in that case it really doesn't matter whether they know or suspect that it's you, and I've heard that at least in some fields, some reviewers even sign their reviews. (In other fields, open reviews are the norm, with the reviews being published under the reviewers' names alongside the article.) It might be that in your particular situation you have a reason to want to protect your anonymity, but this seemed worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: There is also a technical aspect to this question.  At least in math, referee reports are often passed along as latexed pdf files straight from the reviewer.  Without care, the pdf sometimes contains identifying information: for example, my pdf files show that they were compiled on a not-too-common linux distro, which would give me away to at least a few colleagues. Sometimes the default language shows too, depending on the setup.  Anyway, I usually compile on a different computer just to be safe.

Comment: The best way to reveal your identity in reviewing a paper: ask the author to cite one (or more) of your papers.

Comment: The practice I recommend following is to always be polite. If you must write a negative review, explain yourself in the same way you would to a friend or trusted colleague.

Comment: If your premise is true then at some point, people will identify you by your particular style of obfuscation, unless you put a lot of effort into it.

Comment: @GEdgar Thus, the best way to obfuscate your identity is to ask the authors to cite someone else's papers :) I often do point out 3rd party papers which I think are missing and sometimes I do wonder whether the authors conclude I'm the uncited author.

Comment: Wow! I am reading this and I am utterly surprised! I have had no clue that you scientists write your reviews anonymously. What we IT guys call a "peer review" is done by a colleague which you usually *ask* for it! The idea of anonymous review sounds completely weird to me - what a strange word you live in...

Comment: @HonzaZidek In academia we produce research, and then make it publicly available to others. We don't need a peer reviewer to verify our work for us, but rather others want a guarantee that someone has seriously read the work and verified its quality before we spend time reading it. That's why the editor of the journal selects a peer reviewer.  Making it anonymous helps allow the reviewer to provide more honest reviews.

Comment: @Joel: poor scientist who needs to provide more honest review by remaining anonymous. Isn't the true INTERNAL honesty the very first *conditio sine qua non* of science? If I feel dishonored by the fact that someone has found an error in my research, I should change my profession from a scientist to a politician :(

Comment: @HonzaZidek Quite on the contrary.  Staying anonymous can *help* staying honest.  That's a fact and we all know it from normal life and ignoring it just because one feels it *should* be different doesn't make it go away.  A truth is independent from its source.  To assume one needs to know the identity of the author of a review just to take the review into account appears weird to me, and I'm a software developer as well.  It's not the field.

Comment: @Alfe: Well, still I think that certain professions **require** certain morale qualities. You *can* be a dishonest carpenter or an adulterous scientist, but you cannot be a *dishonest* scientist. Honesty belongs to science *inherently*, something like to be a driver you must have a good sight.

Comment: Say "whilst" a lot, and reverse some r's and e's in "er" words.  ;-)

Comment: "inadvertently" use the same turn of phrase as several other people in your field...

Comment: @HonzaZidek Peer review in academic journals has completely different stakes than peer review in IT. People need publications to get tenure. Journals spend months reviewing papers. Peer reviewers aren't just checking for problems, they're recommending whether the paper is accepted or rejected. It's not about "feeling dishonored," it's that rejected paper can be a significant setback for early career people.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Meant to add— we of course ask our peers to read and critique our work all the time, analogous to software peer review.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, don't have enough rep on this site. But I can tell you about JStylo and Stylometry tools (google for them). It helps fingerprint anonymous authors AND anonymize your text. https://github.com/psal/jstylo

Comment: Write your reviews in verse - "This paper is, I must confess/An engineering master-mess/It doesn't make the slightest sense/The author was, I fear, quite dense/It's wording's more than just abstruse/(I think the writer's on the juice)/And in conclusion let me say/Please please please please take it away!".

Answer (score 85):

It's not worth it. Few waste time trying to unblind their reviewers to take retribution for bad reviews. It's just not worth it. The average journal submitter doesn't have enough power to do damage to a random reviewer.

If you need a strategy, trying passing your text through Google Translate to Spanish and back to English. It'll probably be garbage afterwards, but it'll definitely lose any idiomatic turns of phrase that might identify you.

Comment: *The average journal submitter doesn't have enough power to do damage to a random reviewer.* I am working in a very specific field with at most 10 main contributors, most of whom know each other quite well. I have a somewhat distinct style as compared to other guys in the field (at least I believe so), which makes me identifiable. If I write a negative review and I am traced, I risk getting a certain reputation within that group. Subsequently, I may expect some form of revenge (even if subconscious) when it is their turn to review my manuscript. I am not sure I can afford that.

Comment: @RichardHardy He did in fact provide you with a workable method to obfuscate your writing style.

Comment: I'd like to also agree with the "It's not worth it" answer, but would like to point out that even for a young PhD student, it may make sense to try to figure out who wrote the review. This is the case if the review is rejecting due to the topic not being interesting enough, the results not being strong enough, etc. This is somewhat subjective, and the student may want to avoid re-submitting the paper to venues where the same reviewer is likely to be taken. In CS, the researcher may want to save time by identifying conference PC members that should not see the paper again.

Comment: @MarchHo, thank you for pointing out, but that was not my question. I am challenging the statement that I have included in the beginning of my comment.

Comment: I had a reputation with one editor for awhile of being a good reviewer to turn to when he had a borderline paper or a paper with mixed reviews that needed a strong review to steer the authors in the right direction. I don't think that ever came to the knowledge of any authors, and I didn't really care. If your field really is that tiny, then you should cultivate the reputation for being a strong reviewer not just a negative one. Thoughtful, precise, and well backed up reviews are better than ones that simply slam the authors and their work.

Comment: @QuoraFeans, I suppose the sarcasm and tongue-in-cheek aspect of that paragraph was lost on you. I did say it would be garbage.

Comment: @RichardHardy if this is the case won't you be identifiable by your opinions anyway?  e.g. "That must be Richard, because he thinks the theory X is garbage, he always objects to Y and always raises point Z".

Comment: “Few waste time trying to unblind their reviewers to take retribution for bad reviews.” — “Retribution” is a strong word. But in my field it’s common to try guess at the reviewers’ identities (especially in the case of a negative review). And conscious or not, that information is *definitely* taken into account when judging your peers and choosing who to collaborate with, how to interact at conferences and, yes, how to review their papers in turn. I wouldn’t even condemn this; it’s simply human.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'll condemn it. There are lots of things that appear to be "simply human" that we do not condone or even blow off. Do I think that this is as bad as violence, no, but I do think it's bad for academia. If you guess wrong, then you may miss a good opportunity to collaborate or will wrongly take revenge when reviewing. Fight that urge to know, and accept your reviews with honor and humility as best you can.

Comment: So that's why these reviews are so hard to read.  I hope after you translate it back to English you at least edit it.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, don't have enough rep on this site. But I can tell you about JStylo and Stylometry tools (google for them). It helps fingerprint anonymous authors AND anonymize your text.

Comment: @BillBarth Actually, it can be just the opposite as well. I recently received a very critical review on my work that was quite helpful to me, despite leading to a rejection. I wish I had the opportunity to talk with this reviewer before the actual peer review because it is very hard to find others with good advice in my research concentration. Sadly, I don't know the community well enough to guess at the author yet, but I would love to collaborate if I find him/her.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro, you might try communicating with the reviewer through the editor to see if they are willing to reveal themselves.

Answer (score 70):

Assuming that you really want to do this, here are some strategies that should not strongly diminish the readability of your review:

- If you are from an English-speaking country: Use the spelling conventions of another English-speaking country (e.g., British instead of American English).
- Switch to a strongly different punctuation convention, e.g., [the French one](http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-punctuation.htm):

  > On page 2, the authors write : « We could not find any evidence for this. »
- If you typically tend to write long sentences, split sentences up as much as possible. If you tend to write short sentences, make them slightly longer than you’re comfortable with.
- Try to use certain words particularly often, e.g., *particularly.* On the other hand, if you are particularly fond of certain words, avoid them entirely (of course, the main challenge is to become aware of this in the first place).
- If your field has two competing notations for something, use the other one.
- Unless this is a feature of your native language, drop [articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29), in particular if this does not inhibit understanding your review. On the other hand, if your native language is not particularly fond of articles or does not have them at all, use an article wherever possible.
- After you wrote your review, try to replace every rarer, non-technical word by a synonym found in a thesaurus.
- Exclusively use either the [simple past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_past) or the [present perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect). Or: Exclusively use either [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Progressive) forms or non-progressive ones.
- To make you seem German, capitalise some arbitrary nouns, but do not capitalise adjectives derived from proper names:

  > I disagree with the use of bayesian Statistics.

Comment: Very funny suggestions, and very good ones - to what lengths will one go to - even legitimately - hide ones presence :-) But, in any case, "nullum inultum remanebit" - write your reviews (also your negative ones), as if you will be, at some point, found out. Always. No exception, even if you are angry at the author (for stupidity, intransigence, or not citing you).

Comment: Dropping articles and excessively using articles are *both* symptoms of speakers whose native languages do not have articles. I’m afraid the only effective way of concealing such origin of the reviewer is to learn how to use articles properly, which may be quite difficult.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek actually, no. In Italian we have articles, but they are used differently with respect to English, and Italians writing in English tend to use too many articles or misplaced articles.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Also, I only ever witnessed an overuse of articles with native speakers of languages featuring articles so far. Anyway, this is not necessarily about reality but about possible deductions of the paper’s author.

Comment: Pretending you are American if British is not as easy as people think. Pretending you are British if American is likely to be worse. Moreover, you risk your review being misleading if you succeed enough to convince the author but not enough to actually use language correctly. It can really matter whether a reviewer is US or UK. I had a referee say, 'This is quite well done.' That means entirely different things on different sides of the Atlantic!

Comment: The typical American trying to sound English will sound like a Dickens character. Which I guess is a pretty good way to conceal your usual writing style. I will say though that no even marginally competent German writer would capitalise nouns - that's a trivial rule that everybody internalises quickly. You recognize German speakers by how they structure their sentences - that's *really* hard to hide (extra points if you manage to make whole paragraphs single sentences :-) ).

Comment: @Voo: Being German and a moderator on German language, I see quite a lot of English writing by Germans and capitalising the occasional noun is quite a common mistake – just that you know how it’s done correctly, does not mean that you will avoid the mistake all the time. I even notice it happening to me occasionally.

Comment: You forgot to mention:  From all of these suggestions above, pick any four to avoid to be traceable by being absolutely untraceable ;-)

Comment: I used to write reviews in American English to hide my identity in reviews back when I was young and naive enough to worry about such things :)
I tend to see over-use of articles by Russian and other Eastern European  writers, and under-use of articles by Chinese writers.

Comment: Instead of using "the other one", one should use random choice (and perhaps repeat the whole process if we got too close to our own style). Of course, we can push this even further, e.g. download a number of papers, and use the style that happens most often which is different enough for you.

Comment: You could always keep people off guard by following these rules only *some* of the time.  E.g. use British and American spellings interchangeably, maybe even with the same word or in the same sentence.  Of course you'll then run the risk of coming off as just being a sloppy writer.  Not sure which is worse...

Comment: I'm -1 on this one because I don't think it's wise to intentionally make mistakes, and it may undermine your influence or reputation as a reviewer.

Comment: Along the same lines as your suggestion for seeming to be German, you could pretend to be French by using "precise" as a verb.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Using British and American spellings interchangeably might become a bad idea if one of your suggestions for revision of the paper is to use either the British or the American spelling consistently.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, *you* do not obfuscate review - review obfuscates you!

Comment: I am disagreeing. If I were being to be using exclusively the progressive form, I would certainly be wondering whether people are thinking I am speaking funny. And if moreover I have been using perfect instead of past, as you have been suggesting, I would most likely be being mocked and also ignored. Have you not been realizing this? – Nah, for sanity's sake, don't try too hard to be wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: You are confusing the past and the subjunctive and you are not using the progressive form correctly.

Comment: A technique I've used myself to make a review seem more German: replace some random "and"s with "unds".

Answer (score 21):

To add to Bill's answer, most scientists would agree that it is not productive to try figuring out who a reviewer may be, and consciously avoid thinking about it too hard. I make that a point when talking to my students and postdocs. I'm not sure most are that explicit about it, but I've never spoken to anyone who actively tried to find out who a reviewer might be, but I've spoken to many who agree that it's the wrong thing to do.

The whole point being: nothing good can come of it if you know who your reviewers are. But you can violate the spirit of peer review and alienate colleagues if you try too hard. So just let it go.

For you, this means: don't try too hard to obscure your identity.

Comment: Would you have any response to my comment under Bill Barth's answer?

Comment: Yes. You are doing your professional duty when writing a review, and everyone understands that. So, when you write a negative review, then presumably because you had good reasons. You will get a bad reputation if you're confusing being an objective reviewer with being a princess who wants it her way over style issues. But if you have good arguments to reject an article, or to suggest a major revision, then nobody can really argue about that, or fault you for that. Even luminaries understand that they don't have a right to get their papers published the way they were initially submitted.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth you are assuming a lot about a small sample size that the author is closely acquainted with when you say "everyone understands that" and 'nobody can really argue about that".  

I've been in groups doing *math* and had people get angry at me because I pointed out holes in their arguments.  Holes which would have cost them points on their homework and made them look dumb.  I was doing it completely professionally and politely, but they were reacting in an irrational manner, because sometimes humans do that.

(I grant that in the abstract, you are correct, just to be clear.)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, in the perfect world this would be true.  But then we wouldn't need reviewers, since there wouldn't be any mistakes in any of the research.

Comment: @dan1111 -- that's not a very pragmatic point of view. Papers become better by peer review, simply because authors get to see another point of view. This is not a question of "perfect" or "imperfect" worlds, just the reality of writing.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest that you forget your current train of thought. Openly sign your review and write it as if you would tell it to the author's face. If your colleague wrote a bad piece, then help him by pointing out how it could be improved, in a way that does not make him lose his face. If you are working in a falsifiable field and he made an objective error, then explain that error in an objective way (stating facts etc.).

Your new problem is then to figure out how to write your reviews like that, and there are plenty of techniques for that (there should be plenty of resources out there about how to put out criticism without the hurt factor). This is much more healthy and probably also easier than obfuscating your identity.

Comment: "Write your review as if you would tell it to the author's face". This should be upvoted 10 times.

Answer (score 10):

If you are really serious about maintaining your anonymity, you should keep in mind that not just the style of your writing, but also the content of what you write, contain major clues as to your personality and hence (given how small your field is) to your identity.

I therefore suggest choosing a random subset of your recommendations to the author(s) and flipping them: e.g., if you were going to suggest making the paper longer, tell them to make it shorter instead; if you thought of suggesting to collect more data, tell them they have too much, etc.

Finally, for extra safety, also flip the accept/reject bit. With this technique, your anonymity will be virtually guaranteed.

Comment: Upvoting under the premise that this is a humorous answer that wants to contradict OPs question.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it really isn't worth trying too hard. But an easy measure to take might be to switch from American -> British English (or vice-versa). Of course, this will only work if your review happens to contain enough words that will indicate your dialect.

Comment: No. It is *far* too easy to inadvertently say something you don't mean. 'This paper is quite good.' Will you remember which side of the Atlantic you are meant to be from? Are you even aware of the difference in meaning? And this is just one example.

Comment: I always mention "shrimp on the barbie" in all of my reviewer comments, for precisely this reason.  No one has ever figured out who I am.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, become a better writer. Seriously. Take writer training classes, including the ones aimed at fiction writers. Read books on writing style, non-fiction as well as fiction. Study writing styles. When you read something, take some time to note the phrases, grammar, etc., not just the content. Understand how words and grammar bring meaning across.

Also try some role playing. Go to impro theater classes, or play a RPG. Every now and then, imagine being somebody else, and talking and writing like them.

Once you have developed a sufficient understanding of prose to identify how exactly your style differs from others, you will be able to create one or more personas with a distinct writing style. Write your reviews as this persona.

This requires quite a bit of commitment and you will need to learn considerable skills in that area. On the plus side, you will not only be able to hide your identity, but you will also gain a lot of mastery in writing, which is a very valuable skill for a person judged on the quality of his written publications.

It is up to you to decide if the considerable effort is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

To review in  a less personal way, I avoid the "I", and use the third person writing. I thus  write "the reviewer suggests", "to the reviewer". Accordingly, I write "in the paper", "The authors". This helps me take a more distant look at the work under review.

I learned this from a colleague, received a review in this style. Thus, at least three reviewers use this technique (I won't be detected so easily).

Comment: The comment above appears to suggest that using the third person and other such indirect references will make the review less personalized.  This is a technique generally to be encouraged.  Author of said comment is to be commended and should receive the adulation of the community.  :)

Comment: The reviewer conveys interesting insights and the author wishes to acknowledge his useful contributions to the final version of the post

Comment: Based on the general reaction one would expect (on the assumption that said reviewer is human), it is to be believed that the review would appreciate the author's acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymity is ultimately about separating yourself from your speech. Use a standard and concise style that avoids all biases, irrelevance to the purpose of the work under review, and unprofessional language or conduct.

Doing so will additionally elevate any intellectual endeavor and need not be done for privacy purposes alone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an automated paraphrasing tool such as [Spinbot](https://spinbot.com/).

The text will need a little bit of editing afterwards... here's what it made of your question:

> Benefits anybody have in any way guidance for jumbling one's written work style when assessing papers? I have an apprehension that I would accidentally utilize the same turn of expression in a ref report as in some distributed work, consequently uncovering my character, and I'm interested if there is a decent broad practice to take after to alleviate this however much as could reasonably be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago my colleague was asked to review an article written by a well known person in our field of research, who was familiar with the writing style of my colleague.

There were serious issues with the paper and my colleague intended to write a very negative review but wanted to maintain anonymity.

We discussed the issues and I wrote the review. Problem solved.

The article was rejected, but later published in another journal.